# Puppeteer does not return current value of the input

Tags: puppeteer

The initial input value is 0 but the page executes some script and sets it to something else. I want to wait until it is replaced.

```
const input =  await page.$('#amount');
await page.waitFor(10000); // Just to make sure the page's script executes
const value1 = await page.evaluate(input => input.getAttribute('value'), input); // evaluates to 0
const value2 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#amount').value); // evaluates to 0
```

Puppeteer is running without headless option and I can see the current value is not 0. If I execute `document.querySelector('#amount').value` in chrome devtools then it also works. Moving the wait to the beginning also does not help. I have tried using a for loop and retrieving a fresh node each time after a set period. The value was always 0.

I could not find any information about the current input values.

Comment: Maybe try `await page.waitForFunction(() => document.querySelector('#amount').value !== '0')`?

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Is there a way to retrieve the shown text directly?

Comment: `const value2 = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#amount').value);` should work. Maybe it is some timing issue. `const value1 = await page.evaluate(input => input.getAttribute('value'), input);` only gives the hardcoded attribute, not the live value.

Comment: My input element `<input id="email" name="email" class="eR um un" placeholder="" type="text" minlength="" maxlength="" pattern=".*" data-e2e="account-details-email-input" value="bctest@mailinator.com">` I am unable to extract the value ; `const editValue = await page.evaluate(() => {  return  document.querySelector('[data-e2e="account-details-email-input"]').value})`
Error- Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)